# Can't we use numeric index on arrays with key value in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, offset, key-value

I defined an array in PHP using key value pairs like this:

```
$myArray = (
    'item1' => 'val1',
    'item2' => 'val2',
    'item3' => 'val3'
);
```

But whenever I need to use one of the stored value inside this array using numeric index like `$myArray[1]`, I get error below:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 ...

Previously I though numeric indexes are always created when we define array members, but now this error is telling me I was wrong.

My questions is: Can't we use numeric indexes on arrays that have been created using key value pairs in PHP?

Comment: you have an error in your array `'item3; => 'val3'` needs to be `'item3' => 'val3'`

Comment: ^ probably just *fat-fingered* it. That `;` is right next to `'` on the kb.

Comment: you are all so missing the term `array` ie `= array(`

Comment: and, that too ^ but `$myArray = [
    'item1' => 'val1',
    'item2' => 'val2',
    'item3' => 'val3'
];` would be valid if PHP > 5.4

Comment: @Fred-ii- But he's using round brackets, not square brackets, anyway.

Comment: @frosty `foreach($myArray as $var){

echo $var;

}` pans out along with what I wrote up there. Result: *val1val2val3*. I know it doesn't solve the question, but it's valid. So, he probably just *fat-fingered* the brackets too, *who knows*.

Comment: @frosty *Addendum* to above. Using round brackets would have thrown them `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)...` so I think they did fat-finger it in the question.

Comment: He fat-fingered not just one bracket, but two? lol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you can't access a value of an associative array via numerical index. But you can pass your array through `array_values` first to get what you want:

```
echo array_values($myArray)[1];
```

http://php.net/array_values

> array_values() returns all the values from the array and indexes the array numerically.

Comment: Shouldn't you convert the whole array before echoing them?

Comment: @frosty Depends on what you need. If you just need one value, this is easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) when you need it explicitly:

```
$arrayKeys = array_keys($myArray);

echo $myArray[$arrayKeys[0]];
```

Or in a foreach:

```
foreach($myArray as $key=>$value) {
//$ key stores item1,item2,item3
//$value stores $val1, val2,val3
}
```